Как программно записать в общедоступную директорию внутреннего хранилища файл?
Примером такой директории может быть [Download], [Documents] и т.п.
Как создать новую общедоступную директорию на том же уровне, что и указанные?
Или в качестве поддиректории к ним.
Все мои попытки создать такую директорию и записать туда файл (выуженные из интернета) приводили либо к Exception, либо к созданию директорий или файлов по пути /Android/data/...
Хотелось бы увидеть короткий рабочий пример.
PS: Меня интересует именно ВНУТРЕННЕЕ хранилище, а НЕ внешняя карта памяти!

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Мой вопрос в том или ином виде встречается очень часто, например, такой:
https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.652d322d-6734f659-51e0fbb8-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/21611288/android-save-files-in-internal-storage-in-a-directory-publicly

Как, наприvер, делаюn это разработчики многочисленных файловых менеджеров?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28183933/16916244

а какой тип файла? с изображениями все очень просто.

Спасибо, @Wlad! Ты реально помог!

Привожу реальный код:
/*
Код для создания поддиректории [MyNewDirectory] директории 
  [Downloads],
и создания в [MyNewDirectory] файла "MyNewFile.txt"
и записью в него строки "Привет!"
*/
File dirDownLoads = 
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dirDownLoads.getAbsolutePath() = " + 
dirDownLoads.getAbsolutePath());
File dir = new File(dirDownLoads, "MyNewDirectory");
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyNewDirectory is created!");
}
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dir.getAbsolutePath() = " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
File file = new File(dir + File.separator + "MyNewFile.txt");
try {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    outputStream.write("Привет!".getBytes());                            //             
    outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "[IOException] Problems with file!");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "file.getAbsolutePath() = " + file.getAbsolutePath());
}
     

